# How can I fix a .tar.gz being downloaded as html?

Tags: ubuntu, gzip, html

I'm trying to download this file https://www.apache.org/dyn/closer.cgi/hadoop/common/hadoop-3.3.6/hadoop-3.3.6.tar.gz with wget. When I try to unpack it with tar I get the following error:

```
gzip: stdin: not in gzip format
tar: Child returned status 1
tar: Error is not recoverable: exiting now.
```

I used "file" to check the filetype and it's HTML. What can I do to make sure that the file is downloaded as a gzip instead of html? Thanks for the help!!

Comment: _What can I do to make sure that the file is downloaded as a gzip instead of html?_ Use the actual correct link for the file.  Even though that link ends in `.tar.gz`, it is a plain html page.

Answer (score 4):

The link points to an html-page. Visit that page with a browser and find the link to the actual package.

Comment: That was stupid of me, thank you!

Answer (score 2):

With a read of 3 seconds from link:

```
wget https://dlcdn.apache.org/hadoop/common/hadoop-3.3.6/hadoop-3.3.6.tar.gz
```

Comment: Yeah, definitely should have checked that out. Link was provided to me for class from a professor. Thank you for the help!